# Excel formula based on what date it is and what property it has

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a cash flow excel file for my firm. I created almost all other parts but I stuck on how to do loops in excel, or is it possible at all.

Lets look at this Expenses sheet:
[image: A picture]

There are Activities column and its a list of pre-defined codes. There are a Date and Cost, which are most important and I'm gonna use them.

I also have Exchange Rate sheet, which looks like this:

[image]

Problem: I want to display at column **H** in `Expenses Sheet`:

- if date is within the range of any date in Exchange rate's table take that particular's date of Exchange rate value and show it there

I can do it for one day.

`=IF(AND(YEAR(B3)=YEAR(Expenses!E2);MONTH(Expenses!E2)=MONTH('Developer''s room'!E6));F6;FALSE)`

I need it do be looped or something like this, so it can do this for that particular date untill it finds the one with match.

Comment: In the exchange rate sheet, the year is 2016 or 2017?

Comment: @NiteshHalai, its a range of date from 2016-2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the VLOOKUP formula with the approximate match:

```
=G2/VLOOKUP(E2,Sheetname!E:F,2,TRUE)
```

Comment: What is your exchange rate for 01/05/2017?

Comment: I just changed those from 2016 to 2017 for the sake of this experiment. its 8.82

Comment: yes, I read the documentation though.. it looks like exactly what I want, wondering why it doesnt work

Comment: what i got : `=G2/VLOOKUP(E2;'Developer''s room'!E2:F51;2;TRUE)`

Comment: well, I found my error. It works now as it should. Thanks a lot for your help. The problem was that I had two same dates..

Comment: Ensure that you change the E2:F51 to absolute reference ($E$2:$F$51) before dragging down.